# Question about finite ring with more than one element; division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings

> A finite ring with more than one element and no zero divisors is a division ring. (Hungerford, *Algebra*, Exercise 6, Chapter 3, Section 1.)

This a problem taken from Hungerford's graduate algebra text. Hungerford defines left and right zero divisors and then says that an element is a zero divisor if it is both a left and right zero divisor. I took a peek at a solution to the exercise and the author of the solution says that for $r \in R-\{0\}=R^*$, $rR^*=R^*=R^*r$. I might be missing something.

Say I want to show $rR^*=R^*$. Pick $ry \in rR^*$. If $ry=0$ then this implies that $r$ is a left zero divisor and $y$ is a right zero divisor.

> $R$ has no zero divisors, but I am assuming this doesn't exclude the possibility of elements being a right zero divisor or a left zero divisor. I am thinking correctly here?

Just answering this step is fine, I think I can try to continue working on the problem from this point. Thanks.

Comment: The poster here is asking about a particular step, but not the entire question. The solution to the  question itself actually appears elsewhere, though http://math.stackexchange.com/q/591725/29335 , for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Lemma: A ring with no nonzero two-sided zero divisors has no nonzero one-sided zero divisors.

Suppose $ab=0$ for nonzero $a,b$. Then $ba\neq 0$. But also $(ba)^2=0$, contradicting the hypothesis. Therefore such $a,b$ do not exist.